# why can't the iso be verified?

Tags: mac

I have a MacBook Pro running on Mountain Lion. I am trying to install the newest version of Ubuntu for power pc, and after trying to burn the ISO onto the dvd, it says it could not verify the ISO. What should I do?

Comment: Which newest version?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Which program are you using to burn the ISO?

Comment: I downloaded ubuntu power pc 12.04 and used Disk Utility on my Macbook to burn it onto a DVD-R. It burned it onto the disk, but failed to verify

Comment: The main problem is that you've downloaded the wrong ISO! You need the alternative download and not the power pc version. The power pc is only for computers running a power pc processor, like a emac, power mac G3, etc. The macbook you have has an intel processor.

Comment: @Alvar What do you mean by "alternative"? He needs the 64-bit ISO, right?

Comment: @Jop yes you are right he just needs the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

There might have been a connection problem while downloading ISO, or while saving downloaded content to disk the operating system you are using may made a mistake, it happens from time to time. You can try re-downloading the ISO.

Also, before burning ISO to media check if md5sum of ISO is correct. Hashes are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

Answer (score 0):

First, check to make sure the ISO you downloaded isn't corrupted. In the Mac OS X command line, you can run the, MD5 command to get the checksum for the disk image:

```
md5 /path/to/image/ubuntu-12.04.2-server-amd64.iso
```

You can then compare the result of the command against the expected result that is listed here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.2/MD5SUMS

If your image is correct, and you're still having problems, it's probably because ubuntu has been making disk images lately using a new hybridized file format that doesn't place nice with the Mac OS X operating system. Some users have found command line operations that will allow them to rebuild the ISO for Mac OS X, but I have yet find a bulletproof method. Try your luck starting here:

- http://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation
- [Why can't I mount the Ubuntu 12.04 installer ISOs in Mac OS X?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153833/why-cant-i-mount-the-ubuntu-12-04-installer-isos-in-mac-os-x)