# Disk image difficulties for old macbook

Tags: system-installation, uefi, iso, macbook

So I'm trying to install Ubuntu as a single boot on a pretty old macbook (circa late 2006). I downloaded the `ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` and DD'd it to a flash drive, but my old macbook wouldn't read it (no valid filesystem sort of thing).  I tried burning it to a DVD, same issue; if I tried to boot it while holding down the option key, the laptop would literally spit out the DVD before even booting up, and then show just its own disk.

Naturally I did some googling, and found http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2094075.  Basically, the .iso is packaged weirdly and mac doesn't like it.  So I tried the instructions mentioned on that page (`dd if=/disk/rdiskNs1 of=./ubuntu-reg_iso.iso bs=1m`); that resulted in an image with one small partition that I can mount, which contains `/efi/boot/bootx64.efi,grubx64.efi`.  Assuming the other partition was simply hidden and would be available to the EFI bootloader, I burned this to a DVD.  (BTW I'm doing all these things on a mid 2010 macbook pro running OS X.8.5, not on the old machine.) But when I restart the macbook holding down the option key, it doesn't give me the option to boot off of the DVD.

I also followed the instructions here: [Why can't I mount the Ubuntu 12.04 installer ISOs in Mac OS X?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153833/why-cant-i-mount-the-ubuntu-12-04-installer-isos-in-mac-os-x) and used Keka to extract the original .iso, so I have its contents:

```
EFI/    
Master.cdr    
README.diskdefines    
[BOOT]/    
autorun.inf    
boot/    
casper/    
dists/    
install/    
isolinux/    
md5sum.txt    
pics/    
pool/    
preseed/    
wubi.exe
```

But I assume I can't just stick all those in a new .iso and burn that; there's some formatting that has to be done.  Right?

Comment: I would happily try sticking all those things on a DVD if I thought there was a solid chance of it working, but I've already got 2 coasters, so I'm done burning willy nilly for the moment.

Comment: I'm also thinking that all the forum posts I was looking at were wicked old, no idea if I even had the issue right.